# How to truncate text of UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle cell when 'Delete' slides in?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

I have a `UITableView` using the `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` style. I have also increased the cell height by using

```
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

and then calculating the desired height in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. However, when the user slides the 'delete' button in, the text in the cell stretches out and overlaps the upper and lower edges of the cell. How can I truncate the text like it would if I used the default cell style? (or alternatively, could i change the cell height again possibly?)

Comment: This is still an issue. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = textLabelheight/textLabelFontSize;
```